# Get from string to variable in bash

Tags: bash, substitution

I'm writing a bash script to automate some sysadmin stuff. I start with checking that a number of variables are the defined. The way I'm doing that now is like so:

```
function is_defined {
    if [ -z "$2" ]; then
        echo "$1 is not defined"
        exit
    fi
}

is_defined "PROJECTNAME" $PROJECTNAME
```

What I would love to have is a function that only takes one argument: the variable name as a string, checks that it is defined and if it's not defined tell the user so and exit.

What's the right substitution magic to do this in bash?

Comment: _`If  the  first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), a level of variable indirection is introduced`_ - man bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function is_defined {
    if [ -z "${!1}" ]; then
        echo "$1 is not defined"
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

${!a} as @sehe already stated will print value of variable, which name is $1

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, with an exotic parameter expansion: `${!var}`, which expands to the variable whose name is the `$var`.

### Version 1

```
is_defined() {
  if [ -z "${!1}" ]; then
    echo "$1 is not defined"
    exit 1
  fi
}
```

But we can simplify it further:

bash has the `${var?errormsg}` parameter expansion among its lesser-known features. It basically means "if `var` is defined, expand to its value; otherwise, print `errormsg`, set `$?` nonzero and skip to next command". `errormsg` is optional, and defaults to `parameter null or not set` (but the `?` is required). As usual with exotic parameter expansions, it can be modified with a colon (`${var:?errormsg}`) to also error if the variable has an empty value.

In a non-interactive shell, an error generated by this kind of parameter expansion will abort the shellscript.

### Version 2

```
is_defined() {
  : ${!1:?"parameter $1 null or unset"}
}
```

Tested on my MinGW bash just then. The `:` command just ignores all its input, does nothing, and returns success. (This does have the annoying side-effect of polluting your error message by prefixing it with `sh: !1:`; use at own desire.)

Comment: +1 for `${var?msg}` (you should make that version 1). The `set -e` is not necessary; `${var:?msg}` already makes a non-interactive shell exit.